# Automatizing user and password filling in bash by using 'expect' for command 'systemctl restart openvpn'

Tags: bash, expect, openvpn, systemctl

I need to connect my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop to a 2 step secured VPN.
To get it working, I have to write in the terminal 3 times the command 'sudo systemctl restart openvpn':

- First time to provide the 'sudo' password (nothing is returned in console).
- Second time to be requested my username by openvpn ("Enter Auth Username: " is requested in console).
- Third time to be requested my password by openvpn ("Enter Auth Password: " is requested in
  console).

To automatize the process, I have to repeat each time I connect my laptop to Internet, I wrote the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
# shows usage to user
if {$argc!=2} {
   send_user "In order to use this script, you must provide ans user and password:\n"
   send_user "\tsudo $argv0 user password\n"
   exit 1
}
# checks for root privileges
set whoami [exec id -u]
if {$whoami!=0} {
   send_user "You must run this script with root privileges:\n"
   send_user "\tsudo $argv0 user password\n"
   exit 1
}

### Variables
## terminal wait time
#set timeout 1
#match_max 100000

# var to store the user
set user [lindex $argv 0]
# var to store the password
set password [lindex $argv 1]

### start system shell
spawn $env(SHELL)

### First command run: starts the VPN process of asking for the user and password
send -- "systemctl restart openvpn\r"
#expect "\r"

### Second command run: waits for username request
send -- "systemctl restart openvpn\r"
#expect "*?name:*"
expect -exact "Enter Auth Username: "
send "$user\r"

### Third command run: waits for password request
send -- "systemctl restart openvpn\r"
#expect  "*?assword:*"
expect -exact "Enter Auth Password: "
send "$password\r"

expect eof
```

But it is not working as *expected*, `expect` is not providing the correct response to the `systemctl restart openvpn` requests. E.g.:

- Sometimes works properly,
- sometimes fills the incorrect request (enters username when password is requested or viceversa)

But when I run 3 times the script, it fills properly the requests and I get connected.

Any advice would be useful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may need to wait after sending the first `systemctl` for openvpn to do some work before you send the second command. Try adding a `sleep 10` or similar, just to see. If your later `expect` commands timeout (by default after 10 seconds), the script will continue, perhaps before openvpn is ready. Check by adding a `set timeout 30` or similar at the start, just to see.

Comment: I just auto-answered me before I read your comment, I'm going to try your proposal as well, because, although the new scrip version is working, `expect`'s responses are not well synchronized with the terminal outputs. Thanks.

Comment: @meuh, your proposal helped me to synchronize better the `expect` commands and the terminal outputs, avoiding some minor errors. I'm going to add the changes to my self-answer.

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Answer (score 1):

By using the `expect`'s tool `autoexpect` I have found that to fill-in the request field "Enter Auth Password: ", the script have to send the password letter by letter, *i.e.* (simplifying my initial script to focus on the matter):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
spawn $env(SHELL)
match_max 100000

# First command run: start of process
send -- "systemctl restart openvpn\r"
# time between first and second systemctl to synchronize terminal responses
send -- "sleep 5\r"

# Second command run: input username (case username = username)
send -- "systemctl restart openvpn\r"
expect -exact "Enter Auth Username: "
send -- "username"
expect -exact ""
send -- "\r"

# Third command run: input password (case password = flower)
send -- "systemctl restart openvpn\r"
expect -exact "Enter Auth Password: "
send -- "f"
expect -exact "*"
send -- "l"
expect -exact "*"
send -- "o"
expect -exact "*"
send -- "w"
expect -exact "*"
send -- "e"
expect -exact "*"
send -- "r"
expect -exact "*"
send -- "\r"
send -- "exit\r"
expect eof
```

Now, the script works.

Comment: Expect uses [tag:tcl] which can manipulate strings by itself. See http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm

Comment: but i don't think the problem is caused by sending the whole password with one single `send`.

Comment: Note: `send` has options `-s ` and `-h` to send a string char by char slowly, but you probably only really need to wait a bit after getting the prompt before sending the reply (this is because openvpn may be flushing the tty input at this time, ready for the password, and you need to get past that). You don't need to `send "sleep 5"`, as expect has a sleep command.

Comment: I really don't think you need to send the password char-by-char. And it's unusual to have to sleep between sends: you should expect to see your shell prompt instead before sending each systemctl command. I'd suggest you run the script with `expect -d` to enable verbose tracing, and you'll be able to see if your patterns are matching when you think they are.